# Filter predicate function not returning anything and Cannot read property 'data' - MatTableDataSource angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

The below function is not working for the first time when we enter the first letter in the search bar and it returns nothing in the array and later when we remove the letter and continue typing, it is working fine.

```
createFilterPredicate() {
    let myFilterPredicate = function(data:any, filter:string): boolean {
      console.log('data:', data);
      let searchString = JSON.parse(filter);
      return data.admissionno.toString().trim().indexOf(searchString.admissionno) !== -1 &&      
      data.firstname.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.firstname.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    }
    return myFilterPredicate;
  }
```

Actually, when I debug, I see that it is entering the function.After that it is not going into the `myFilterPredicate` function and no data in console and returns nothing. whats problem and how to find it ?..

The complete code is below:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.admissionNoFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((admissionno) => {
      this.filteredValues['admissionno'] = admissionno;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
    });
    this.studentNameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((firstname) =>{
      this.filteredValues['firstname'] = firstname;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
    });
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.createFilterPredicate();
 }

createFilterPredicate() {
    let myFilterPredicate = function(data:any, filter:string): boolean {
      console.log('data:', data);
      let searchString = JSON.parse(filter);
      return data.admissionno.toString().trim().indexOf(searchString.admissionno) !== -1 &&      
      data.firstname.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.firstname.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    }
    return myFilterPredicate;
  }
```

component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="admissionno">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> <Strong> Admission No </Strong> 
                <div>
                  <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="admissionNoFilter" placeholder="Filter">
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
              </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.admissionno}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > <Strong> Student Name </Strong>
              <div>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="studentNameFilter" placeholder="Name Filter">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.firstname + ' ' + element.lastname}} </td>
          </ng-container>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your let property got destroyed as soon as your function call returned.

Change create filter predicate to :-

```
createFilterPredicate(data:any, filter:string) {
      console.log('data:', data);
      let searchString = JSON.parse(filter);
      return data.admissionno.toString().trim().indexOf(searchString.admissionno) !== -1 &&      
      data.firstname.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.firstname.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  }
```

and assign it to datasource like :-

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.createFilterPredicate;
```

Comment: I try this but its not working:(  my prblm is `const myFilterPredicate = function(data:any, filter:string): boolean { console.log('data:', data);     ///// codings   } ` but display only an empty array[]

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.createFilterPredicate();
    this.admissionNoFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((admissionno) => { 
        this.filteredValues['admissionno'] = admissionno; 
        this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues); 
    });
    this.studentNameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((firstname) => { 
        this.filteredValues['firstname'] = firstname; 
        this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues); 
    });
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.createFilterPredicate(); 
}
createFilterPredicate() { 
    let myFilterPredicate = function(data:any, filter:string): boolean { 
        console.log('data:', data); 
        let searchString = JSON.parse(filter); 
        return data.admissionno.toString().trim().indexOf(searchString.admissionno) !== -1 && 
               data.firstname.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.firstname.toLowerCase()) !== -1; 
    }
    return myFilterPredicate; 
}
```

The above code will fix that issue.